# array type 'char [30]' is not assignable

Tags: arrays, c, struct, c-strings

I have some struct called 'List' which contains id, salary, name of worker and pointer to next node of list.
There the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
  int id;
  int salary;
  struct node *next;
  char name[30];
} List;

int main() {
  List *head = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List)); //allocated memory for head
  if(head == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }

  head -> id = 332513075;
  head -> salary = 100;
  head -> name = "Name Lastname";
  // head -> phone = "0532554891";
  // head -> position = "CEO";
  head -> next = NULL;

  print_list(*head);

  return 0;
}
```

Error message: `array type 'char [30]' is not assignable`
What is going wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: Aside: Instead of `List *head = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List));`, consider the tidy `List *head = malloc(sizeof *head);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. That is arrays do not have the assignment operator. You have to copy elements from one array into another.

So instead of this statement

```
head -> name = "Name Lastname";
```

write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( head -> name, "Name Lastname" );
```